# maven add zip file to deploy to remote server

Tags: java, maven, zip, maven-3, maven-deploy-plugin

I have maven project. When I click **install** maven build **zip** and **jar** file in `target` folder.

But when i click **deploy** it only deploy **jar** file and dependencies to remote repository.

**Question**: How I can add zip file to deploy to remote nexus repository with standard maven plugins.

EDIT

`<packaging>custom-zip<packaging>`

Comment: the `.zip` file is part of the `target` folder content, but is it copied to the local `m2` cache? I presume not, only the `.jar` should be there, consistently with the `deploy` behavior then. Can you share more of the concerned `pom.xml` file? Most probably the `zip` file is generated by not attached to the build as additional artifact

Comment: @A_Di-Matteo yes, you right. Only `.jar` in local `m2 cache`.
I just have special plugin `custom-plugin-packaging-zip`
And this plugin make for me `zip` file in `target` folder.
How I can attach this to build as additional artifact?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to properly `install` and `deploy` an additional artifact (a file generated by the build, normally also following its versioning and coherently part of the outcome of the concerned project), you need to **attach** it to the build so that Maven will handle it as official deliverable of its outcome.

To attach a file to the build, you can use the `build-helper-maven-plugin`.

Here is a sample snippet from its [usage](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html) page:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.12</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>attach-artifacts</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <artifacts>
            <artifact>
              <file>the-generated-file</file>
              <type>extension of your file</type>
              <classifier>optional</classifier>
            </artifact>
          </artifacts>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

You should place the configuration above after the plugin declaration which is responsible for the generation of the file, that is, the file should exist when you try to attach it to the build. Look at the `file` configuration element, here you should specify the file, e.g. `target\myfile.zip`. In this case it will be attached during the `package` phase so that the `install` and `deploy` phase would take it into account during their processing.

When invoking

```
mvn clean install
```

You would then see as part of the build output:

```
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.12:attach-artifact (attach-artifacts) @ zip-example ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ zip-example ---
[INFO] Installing C:\data\eclipse-workspace\zip-example\target\zip-example-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to c:\data\m2\repository\com\sample\zip-example\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\zip-example-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\data\eclipse-workspace\zip-example\pom.xml to c:\data\m2\repository\com\sample\zip-example\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\zip-example-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] Installing C:\data\eclipse-workspace\zip-example\sample.zip to c:\data\m2\repository\com\sample\zip-example\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\zip-example-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-optional.zip
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Note: the `sample.zip` was actually copied to the `m2` local repository as `zip-example-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-optional.zip`, hence renamed according to the project configuration (`artifactId`, `version`, `classifier`).

Comment: @ArturGaniev did you try this approach?

Comment: Sorry for late answer.
Thank you very much - it works. !